# Toolbar not visible in layout

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Below is my layout, and when running the toolbar is not visible at all, the two tabs on the tabview take up the entire screen. In the preview in AndroidStudio I do see the ActionBar as I expect it to be at the top. What am I missing?

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/c">


<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" />


<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/c2">


<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
    </RelativeLayout>




<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Here is my activity where I am using this layout:

```
public class TabletGallery extends AppCompatActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    setContentView(R.layout.tablet_gallery);

    // Initilization

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar2);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

User a LinearLayout as your root layout instead.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/c">


<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" />

 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>


<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/c2">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </RelativeLayout>






</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your main layout container is RelativeLayout, so you need to explicitly position your child views *relative* to one another. To make your content display **below** the Toolbar (instead of over it), position it with `android:layout_below="@+id/my_toolbar2"`. It should look something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    ...
    android:id="@+id/c"
    ... >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        ...
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar2"
        ... />

    <RelativeLayout
        ...
        android:id="@+id/c2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/my_toolbar2" 
        ... >

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            ...
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            ... />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            ...
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            ... />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Also, note that I've nested your ViewPager in the inner RelativeLayout (main content container) so that it sits together with your TabLayout.

One additional thing: It'd be helpful if you can properly format your XML or Java before posting your code (AndroidStudio -> Code -> Reformat Code). It's a bit difficult to read what's going on unless it's formatted.

Comment: Thanks. That worked but now I cannot see the tab title indicator that should be at the top of each tab and directly below the toolbar

Comment: Try setting your TabLayout to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`.